Android Fullscreen Intent doesn't work because of this Pop-up setting
I need to show a fullscreen intent notification when receiving an incoming call. However, devices Android 12/13 like Samsung, Oppo, and Xiaomi have their own pop-up settings, as shown in the picture below. If the setting is OFF, the fullscreen intent notification won't work and won't start the activity to show on the lock screen.

This setting isn't developed by Google, so I don't know how to detect if the setting is ON or OFF. Are there any ways to detect it programmatically? Thanks in advance.

I guess we can't check that setting as it differs with various devices. Does full screen notification work when pop up allowed setting is on?

Yes, full screen notification work when pop up allowed setting is on. I wonder are there unofficial ways to detect it?
